# How can I get my regular expression to return only the first match on the line?

Tags: regex

My data contains lines like this:

```
55 511 00,"805, 809, 810, 839, 840",J223,201,338,116,16,200,115,6,P,S,"8,5","25,74",47,242,"55,7"
```

I have tried `,"(.*)",` as a regular expression, but it captures too much of the line. This expression currently returns:

```
,"805, 809, 810, 839, 840",J223,201,338,116,16,200,115,6,P,S,"8,5","25,74",
```

but what I really want is just the first quoted string. Valid results would be:

- `,"805, 809, 810, 839, 840",`
- `805, 809, 810, 839, 840`

How can I capture only that first match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `*` [lazy instead of greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy):

```
,"(.*?)",
```

or match all characters but `"`:

```
,"[^"]*",
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `"([^"]+)`. Group 1 will match `805, 809, 810, 839, 840`

Answer (score 0):

```
/"([^"]+)"/
```

Will do the job! Everything between the "-s

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is greedy, the **.*** will get everything up until the final **"**

So to make it non-greedy, add a **?** at the end of the bracketed part:

```
,"(.*?)",
```

Which should stop it as soon as it reaches the next **"**

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a Non-Greedy Match

There are many ways to handle this, but the simplest and most generic is to use a non-greedy match if your regular expression engine supports it. If it does not, you have to build an expression that knows a lot more about the structure of your data.

#### Some Examples

Here's an example using Perl-compatible regular expressions to split the output:

```
$ pcregrep -o '"(.*?)"' /tmp/foo | head -n1
"805, 809, 810, 839, 840"
```

Here's another example that uses pure Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(".*?")/' /tmp/foo
"805, 809, 810, 839, 840"
```

Here's a third example that uses POSIX extended regular expressions, but which does not support non-greedy matches.

```
$ egrep -o '("[^"]+")' /tmp/foo | head -n1
"805, 809, 810, 839, 840"
```

You may also want to consider splitting your input into fields, and then testing each field until you find a match. A lot just depends on what facilities you have at your disposal.